# Can systemic venous congestion caused by tumor?

Tags: pathogenesis

I am thinking, if 1) little compressed superior caval vena and 2) some vein compression by tumor, can cause systemic venous congestion.

I think this is only in rare occasions.
However, the question is if this is possible.

**Can systemic venous congestion caused by these two factors?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They increase the risk, but are not the causes.
There must be other factors involved which triggers the systemic venous congestion.